# Генератор паролей с маской

Tags: java, kotlin

Итак, задали мне тут задачку, нужно генерировать пароли по маске. При чем не просто генерировать, а выводить все доступные варианты.

Допустим у меня есть входная строка "123456[x][x]", где "123456" - маска. И есть строка alphabet, в которой лежат все символы, например "abcde". И мне нужно перебрать все варианты, например "123456ab", "123456ac", "123456ad" и тд. И я представляю себе как сделать это для одного или двух заменяемых символов, но если их будет больше? Голова уже болит, прошу помощи

Все это я буду собирать в android-прогу, выводящую результат. Не спрашивайте зачем, я и сам не знаю, такой заказ

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, как именно требуется генерировать текст, то вот сразу результат работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При `mask = "123456[x][x]"` и `alphabet = "abcde"`. (Так же алгоритм работает при любом кол-ве `[x]`)

Если вам это и нужно, то объясню идею:

1. Первое что я сделал, это нашел индексы `[x]`, как будто это 1 символ. Например `mask = 1[x]2345[x][x]`, то я получаю массив `1 6 7`.
2. Далее я заменяю все `[x]` на любой один символ, например `?`.
3. Потом пишем функцию `NextSet` для генерации размещений без повторений. Вот [тут](https://prog-cpp.ru/placement/) есть реализация на `c++` (p.s. на сайте есть ошибка в функции `j = n - 2`, а не `j = n - 1`)
4. Остается находить размещения `alphabet` длинной `n` по `count`, где `count` кол-во `[x]` в маске. И заменять по индексам найденным в 1 пункте символы из `alphabet`

Например `mask = 123456[x][x], alphabet = abcde`

1. Массив с индексами `[x]` будет таким `[6, 7]`
2. Далее получаем измененную строку, заменяя `[x]` на `?`. В нашем случае она будет такой: `genStr = 123456??`
3. ...
4. Первое размещение `alphabet` будет `[a, b]`, тогда по индексу `6` в строке `genStr` мы меняем этот символ на `a`, а по индексу `7` на `b`. Потом будет `[a, c]` делаем аналогично.

Все!

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. Надо навык поиска прокачивать, а то видимо я не отсеял ненужное и не нашел тот пример на плюсах

Comment: Дошел в реализации метода, заменяющего содержимое индексов на символы из массива алфавита и голова опять заболела. Не мог бы предоставить код?

Comment: @akella122 а в чем конкретно проблема возникла? У вас же есть массив индексов (назову её `indexes`, строка `genStr` и `alphabet`, который меняется функцией `NextSet`? Тогда берете индекс из массива `indexes` и символ в строке `genStr` под этим индексом должен быть равен просто `alphabet[i]`.

Comment: `genStr[indexes.get(i)] = alphabet[i];`

Comment: @akella122 пожалуйста если вам помог мой ответ и у вас не осталось ко мне доп. вопросов, то пожалуйста отметьте ответ, как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Comment: Я так и не понял как оно работает, а точнее почему должны индексы меняться. Пока я не пойму у меня не получится написать самому. Но дедлайн уже скоро, так что может просто код скинешь? Я хз успею ли сам вьехать так как день загружен

Comment: @akella122 я не могу просто скинуть код из принципов. Я потратил время, чтобы написать алгоритм, а так же расписал его полностью вам. У вас массив индексов никак меняться не должен. По этим индексам вы меняете буквы в `genStr` на `alphabet[i]`, который меняется в функции `NextSet` (очередное сочетание).

Comment: Кажется начинаю въезжать. Прости, что много пишу, попробую вьехать